# Perl Expectation Maximization of log-odds scores of DNA sequences

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap, dna-sequence, expectation-maximization

My overall goal for this code is to find the motif (smaller sequence) in each DNA sequence that will report a maximum log-odds score based on a log-odds scoring matrix. The .txt file I am searching through looks like this:

```
>Sequence 1
TCGACGATCAGACAG
>Sequence 2
TGGGACTTGCACG
```

.... and so on.

I am working on the maximization step of my code at the moment, and I am struggling to calculate a log-odds score of a motif within my DNA sequence. I have code that creates the log-odds scoring matrix - see the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#Above line used in Unix and Linux
#Grome Programming Assignment 2
#E-M
use strict;
use warnings;

# usage: script.pl {motif_width} {dnafile}
#USER SPECIFICATIONS
print "Please enter the filename of the fasta sequence data: ";
my $filename1 = <STDIN>;

#Remove newline from file
chomp $filename1;

#Open the file and store each dna seq in hash
my %id2seq = ();
my $id = '';
open (FILE, '<', $filename1) or die "Cannot open $filename1.",$!;
my $dna;
while (<FILE>)
{
    if($_ =~ /^>(.+)/)
    {
        $id = $1;
    }
    else
    {
        $id2seq{$id} .= $_;
    }
}
close FILE;
foreach $id (keys %id2seq)
{
    print "$id2seq{$id}\n\n";
}

#User specifies motif width
print "Please enter the motif width:\n";
my $width = <STDIN>;

#Remove newline from file
chomp $width;

#Default width is 3 (arbitrary number chosen)
if ($width eq '')
{
    $width = 3;
}
elsif ($width <=0)
{
    print "Please enter a number greater than zero:\n";
    $width = <STDIN>;
    chomp $width;
}

#User specifies number of initial random
#starting alignments
print "Please enter the number of initial random
starting alignments:\n";
my $start = <STDIN>;

#Remove newline from file
chomp $start;

#Default start is 50
if ($start eq '')
{
    $start = 50;
}
elsif ($start <=0)
{
    print "Please enter a number greater than zero:\n";
    $start = <STDIN>;
    chomp $start;
}

#User specifies number of iterations to
#perform expectation-maximization
print "Please enter the number of iterations for 
expectation-maximization:\n";
my $iteration = <STDIN>;

#Remove newline from file
chomp $iteration;

#Default iteration = 500
if($iteration eq '') 
{
    $iteration = 500;
}
elsif ($iteration <=0)
{
    print "Please enter a number greater than zero:\n";
    $iteration = <STDIN>;
    chomp $iteration;
}

#EXPECTATION
#Initialize counts for motif positions
#Incorporate pseudocounts initially
my %mot = map { $_ => [ (1) x $width ] } qw( A C G T );

# Initialize background counts
my %bg = map { $_ => 0 } qw( A C G T );

#Fill background and motif counts
foreach $id (keys %id2seq)
{
    #Generate random start site in the sequence
    #for motif to start from
    my $ms = int(rand(length($id2seq{$id})-$width));

    # Within a motif, count the bases at the positions
    for my $pos (0..length($id2seq{$id})-1)
    {
        my $base = substr($id2seq{$id}, $pos, 1);
        if ($pos >= $ms && $pos < $ms + $width) 
        {
            ++$mot{$base}[$pos-$ms]
                if exists($mot{$base});
        } 
        else 
        {
            ++$bg{$base}
            if exists($bg{$base});
        }
    }
}
#Print the background and motif counts
for my $base (qw( A C G T )) 
{
   print "$base @{$mot{$base}}\n";
}

print "\n";

for my $base (qw( A C G T )) 
{
   print "bg$base = $bg{$base}\n";
}

#Create frequency table of the motifs
#Get sum of the background
my $bgsum = 0;
for my $base (qw( A C G T))
{
    $bgsum = $bgsum + $bg{$base};
}
print "\n$bgsum\n\n";

#Create background frequency table
my %bgfreq = map { $_ => 0 } qw( A C G T );
for my $base (qw( A C G T))
{
    $bgfreq{$base} = $bg{$base} / $bgsum;
    print "bgfreq$base = $bgfreq{$base}\n";
}

#Get sum of each motif position
my @motsum = ( (0) x $width );
for my $base (qw( A C G T))
{
    for my $arrpos (0.. ($width-1))
    {
        $motsum[$arrpos] = $motsum[$arrpos] + @{$mot{$base}}[$arrpos];
    }
}

#Create motif frequency table
my %motfreq = map { $_ => [ (0) x $width ]} qw( A C G T );
for my $base (qw( A C G T))
{
    for my $arrpos (0.. ($width-1))
    {
        $motfreq{$base}[$arrpos] = $mot{$base}[$arrpos] / $motsum[$arrpos];
    }
    print "motfreq$base @{$motfreq{$base}}\n";
}

#Create odds table of motifs
my %odds = map { $_ => [ (0) x ($width) ]} qw( A C G T );

for my $base (qw( A C G T))
{
    for my $arrpos (0.. ($width-1))
    {
        $odds{$base}[$arrpos] = $motfreq{$base}[$arrpos] / $bgfreq{$base};
    }
    print "odds$base @{$odds{$base}}\n";
}

#Create log-odds table of motifs
my %logodds = map { $_ => [ (0) x ($width) ]} qw( A C G T );
for my $base (qw( A C G T))
{
    for my $arrpos (0.. ($width-1))
    {
        $logodds{$base}[$arrpos] = log2($odds{$base}[$arrpos]);
    }
    print "logodds$base @{$logodds{$base}}\n";
}
#####################################################
sub log2
{
    my $n = shift;
    return log($n)/log(2);
}
```

Now, I need to calculate the log-odds score of a motif within each DNA sequence. Then, I will iterate through all possible positions in the sequence and find the maximum score for each sequence. Future work requires me to recall the motif with the max score, but I have not made an attempt at that yet (just wanted to give scope to these max scores).

Strategy: I am going to create a hash of log-odds scores and maximum scores to hold the max scores of each sequence as iterated. To calculate the log-odds score, I will see which element of the log-odds scoring matrix matches the elements in the motif.

```
#MAXIMIZATION
#Determine location for each sequence that maximally
#aligns to the motif pattern
#Calculate logodds for the motif

#Create hash of logodds scores and hash of maxscores
#so each id has a logodds score and max score
 my %loscore = map { $_ => [ (0) x (length($id2seq{$id})-$width) ]} qw( $id ); #Not sure if $id is correct, but I want a loscore for each $id
 my %maxscore = map { $_ => [ (0) x (length($id2seq{$id})-$width) ]} qw( $id ); #Not sure if $id is correct, but I want a maxscore for each $id
 foreach $id (keys %loscore, %maxscore, %id2seq)
 {
 my $len = length($id2seq{$id});
 for my $base (qw( A C G T ))
 {
     for my $pos (0..$len-1)
     {
         if ($id2seq{$id}[$pos] = $mot{$base})
         {
             for my $motpos (0..$width-1)
             {
                 $loscore{$id} = $loscore{$id} + $logodds{$base}[$motpos];
                 if ($loscore{$id} > $maxscore{$id})
                 {
                     $maxscore{$id} = $loscore{$id};
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
 print "$id2seq{$id} logodds score: $maxscore{$id}\n";
 }

#####################################################
sub log2
{
    my $n = shift;
    return log($n)/log(2);
}
```

When I uncomment the maximization step from the code an run it, nothing prints from the maximization section. I do not get any errors, but nothing new prints. I understand that my expectation step can be simplified (I will clean everything up after it works), but I am focused on this maximization step first. I know that there are plenty of flaws in the maximization code, especially when trying to create the log-odds score and max score hashes. Any and all input helps! Thank you in advance for your patience and advice. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach $id (keys %loscore, %maxscore, %id2seq)` doesn't iterate over all three hashes. You probably meant `foreach $id (keys %loscore, keys %maxscore, keys %id2seq)`

`if ($id2seq{$id}[$pos] = $mot{$base})` assigns the value to `$id2seq{$id}[$pos]`. To check for eqaulity you need `if ($id2seq{$id}[$pos] eq $mot{$base})`. But this is probably wrong too since `$id2seq{$id}` should be a string and `$mot{$base}` is an array.

It is not clear how your code should work and it is hard to find errors in such long code samples.

Comment: I'm working on editing the code and updating the post to address your concerns.